# 12.10 Won't Suspend Automatically

Tags: suspend

My computer is a 64 bit desktop running 12.10.  Since upgrading it will not suspend.  In my power settings I have it set for suspend after five minutes.

Comment: do you mean you are unable to shutdown your computer?

Comment: No, I mean suspend.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the time from 5 minutes to "do not suspend" then changed it back.  Now it works.

Comment: You should accept your own answer as correct. :)